# Memory consuption: is better a static variable or not?

Tags: c#

I'm building a dll that have a `Singleton` pattern, so essentially the user add my dll, import the reference and execute a method like so:

```
FooClass.Foo();
```

now suppose that this method return a list each time, and have this structure:

```
static class FooClass
{
   private static List<string> _fooList = new List<string>();
   public static List<string> Foo()
   {    
        _fooList.Clear();
        //list population
        return _fooList;
   }
}
```

how you can see in the method `Foo` I clear each time the list instead of creating new instance of that list I reuse the object.
My question at this point is:

Is better create a new istance of the list inside the method `Foo`, or use the same list object as in my example?

All the result returned will be saved in another object by the user, so I don't need to keep the list in memory.

Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I think that problems can arise if you call the methods several times in async methods. Several methods will attempt to access the same list _fooList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is better create a new instance of the list inside the method Foo, or use the same list object as in my example?

The two approaches are not equivalent, because `clear` modifies the instance that may be in use by some other part of your program. This may lead to significant problems, especially in concurrent environments. Given that the result returned will be saved in another object by the user, the problems are virtually guaranteed in your case if you use `clear`.

> I don't need to keep the list in memory.

Then remove the static `_fooList`, and simply create a new object each time the method is called. Clearing the singleton on every single call defeats the purpose of having a singleton in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for that I'll treasure